# Does passing XML as a parameter protect me against SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-injection

Say I build an XML document from user input and do nothing to cleanse it. If I pass that XML string as a parameter using ADO to a stored proc which then queries it and inserts the values into a table, am I still protected since it started as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you escape that XML by replacing ' with '', you'll be protected.

```
<doc>
    <element attrib='value' />
</doc>
```

becomes

```
'<doc>
    <element attrib=''value'' />
</doc>'
```

**EDIT**
Unless you're using ADO to add a DbParameter. That automatically does the replacement for you, and protects you against SQL injection.

Comment: I'm doing this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Populations", xmlDoc.InnerXml())`

Comment: Yes, that syntax is protected against SQL injection, and you should not further encode the XML.

Comment: For the record, any value you pass to `AddWithValue` will be protected against SQL injection, unless you use that value to build dynamic SQL in the stored procedure.

Comment: Obviously, injection is a pretty serious thing. Do you have any links to validate what you're telling me? I haven't found anything thus far.

Comment: I can find something if you wish, but SQL injection happens when a hacker artificially closes out a string with an apostrophe. Apostrophes are escaped by doubling up on them (''). You can definitely test this yourself, and try passing a single apostrophe in your SQL statement.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx: "Parameter collections such as SqlParameterCollection provide type checking and length validation... SQL Server does not treat it as executable code."